# textContent.replace not working within my function

Tags: javascript

I dont know why this is the case but my replace does not work. It is somehow unusual considering my syntax is correct.

```
info.textContent.replace('Title', "replaced");
```

where info is the variable that stores an element. It should actually replace all instances of Title with "replaced". I prefer not using innerText due to compatibility issues and innerHTML due to security risks. textContent is supported by firefox and I have no idea what is going on.

I would appreciate some insight. I am learning javascript and tips for best practice are welcome.

Below the full code in Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r7bL6vLy/123/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works, it's just replace method returns new string you need to assign back:

```
info.textContent = info.textContent.replace('Title', "replaced");
```

Comment: So hang on there. This is really new haha. So I really need to assign back? I thought it replaces the text already. So my method returns the replacement which is why it didnt update the dom

Comment: No, it returns a new string. Javascript strings are immutable.

Comment: No, strings are immutable. It means that you can't modify it "in place" without creating new string.